# Seaborn histplot with dates doesnt respect bins flag

Tags: python, seaborn

When trying to make a seaborn histplot with dates and a custom number of bins the histplot seems to ignore the flag.  I've tried using the data as a series and list of `datetime` objects as well as a list of strings.  Neither seems to work well.

some sample data:

```
[datetime.date(2022, 5, 18),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 31),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 21),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 20),
 datetime.date(2022, 4, 22),
 datetime.date(2022, 2, 22),...]
```

Plotting with command:
`sns.histplot(data=t_data, bins=5)`

Gives me:
[image]

Is seaborn not capable of doing hist plots with datetime information?

Comment: Did you try `pd.to_datetime(...)` with the latest pandas, matplotlib and seaborn versions?

Comment: Dang.  It was that easy.  For whatever reason having a series of type `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` worked when a series of type `'datetime.date'` didnt.  Lesson learned?

Comment: @JohanC do you want to make your suggestion an answer so i can mark it as solved?

Comment: seaborn tests for dates with `pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype`; maybe it could handle `datetime.date` too but it would need to go around pandas somehow.

Comment: @DChaps Feel free to post your own version of the answer

Answer (score 0):

For some reason pandas will accept and use datetime.date objects to create the plot correctly *but* when passing it onto other parts of the function it may not function correctly, for example binning.  Binning requires that the series be in pandas datetime format as opposed to the more generic datetime format

Doesn't work:

```
dates = pd.DataFrame([datetime.date(2022, 5, 18),
                    datetime.date(2022, 1, 31),...])
print(type(dates.at[0,0]))
Out:
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Does work with bins (and probably other features)

```
dates[0] = pd.to_datetime(dates[0])
print(type(dates[0][0]))
Out:
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```